# How do I make my own laptop Cmos battery

Tags: motherboard, bios, battery, laptop-repair, cmos

The people on your site helped me find a Cmos battery for my laptop. https://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-OEM-FOR-HP-Pavilion-dm3-dm3-1100-Series-Battery-Cmos-Resume-RTC-/264449233544

But I realized this battery is probably just as old as my laptop one. So probably not good. So I was thinking I can buy one or two of these and cut and put in a new battery. That way I don't ruin the adapter I have. Plus one or 2 I can practice cutting and adding the new battery.

So how do I make my own? How will I know which battery to buy? Is this a rechargeable Cmos battery so if I put in another non rechargeable one will it cause leaks? How can I find a rechargeable one?

My laptop is a Hp Pavillion Dm3t-1100. Looks like 2007 or 2009 ish. Runs windows 7

Comment: "probably just as old as my laptop one" Ad says its NEW? Go with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purchase the eBay battery, take it apart (the plastic cover) so you can see how the battery unit was assembled, buy a CMOS battery or 2 of the same type, and re-assemble the unit with the new battery replacement(s). Cover with black tape or shrink wrap, check the voltages at the plug to ensure correct and then put in the computer.

Comment: What will I need to connect the wires to the battery? Just electric tape from dollar store or something special to connect the wire to the battery?

Comment: The wires are connected by soldering or a "weld" of some sort. This is why I suggest you purchase the eBay unit so you can see exactly how it goes together.

Comment: Definitely *not* soldering. Usually, the wires are crimped to flat metal tabs which are spot welded to the battery.